# Is there a way to know whether the current method was used in a chained call?

Tags: laravel, php-7

I want to perform additional operations when a set of function are called in a chain.

I have seen this happening in Laravel query builder but I wasn't able to find the incumbent logic behind it. It defines where clauses in a set, if they are chained and separate otherwise (In the whereNested function callback).

```
$q->whereNested(function (Builder $q) {

    // Generates "Where (first = 1 and second = 2) or third = 3"
    $q->where('first', 1)->where('second', 2);
    $q->orWhere('third', 3);

});
```

Is there a way to know this while executing the function? If not, can someone point me to the logic used by Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php function `debug_backtrace` to get a list of all the called functions, as for the logic used you can find it in

[where](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b4fe271c9001b79dacdb76075e32ad795579ceb7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L583)

[orWhere](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b4fe271c9001b79dacdb76075e32ad795579ceb7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L727)

[whereNested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b4fe271c9001b79dacdb76075e32ad795579ceb7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1282)

all three methods are in the query builder class `Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder`

Comment: The question was to know whether a function was called through chaining or not. Depending different actions could be taken. It was not about which function was called as the user is in the same scope.